# How to set a valid prop path for nested data on a table - Element UI - Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component, element-ui

I'm trying to validate a form, part of which is represented in a table using element-ui. But I can't pass a valid prop to the el-form-item.

The data model looks something like this.

```
form: {
    invoices: [
        {
            amount: '',
            items: [{ name: '', value: '' }]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the html part I have something like this:

```
<template v-for="(invoice, index) in form.invoices">
    <el-form-item :prop="`invoices.${index}.amount`" :rules="rules.invoiceAmount">
        <el-input/>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-table :data="invoice.items">
        <el-table-column prop="name">
            <template scope="scope" slot-scope="scope">
                <el-form-item :prop="`invoices.${index}.items.${scope.$index}.name`" :rules="rules.items">
                    <el-input/>
                </el-form-item>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</template>
```

The second `<el-form-item>` is not validated due to an error

> "Error: please transfer a valid prop path to form item!"

I also tried passing as a prop the following

```
items.${scope.$index}.name
```

but that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: `invoices[index].amount`?

Comment: @destoryer
the validation for the invoice amount works ok. this `:prop="`invoices.${index}.amount`"`
what throws an error is the item name field inside the table. so basically the path to that item name would be something like invoices.index.items.itemIndex.item right?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using string template literals.

Comment: I would replace `invoices.${index}.items.${scope.$index}.name` with `invoice.items[index].name`.

Comment: according to their docs, the prop is actually a string which represents the **key** (not the actual value) of the model you're referring. If I pass in what you're suggesting, the error is not shown but the validation is still not present. For a fixed prop the validation works so it's only a problem of path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct path would be `invoices[${index}].items[${scope.$index}].name`